# Custom validator for date before in angular

Tags: angular, date, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validator

I want to write a custom `dateValidator` with reactive forms to check if an inputed date is before today.

**Component.html**

```html
<form class="container" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    ...
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Birthday</mat-label>
      <input  matInput [matDatepicker]="birthdayDatepicker" formControlName="birthday">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthdayDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #birthdayDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Component.ts**

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name : [,Validators.required],
      email: [,Validators.email],
      birthday: [,dateValidator],
      role: [,Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

What can write here? I would like the value of the input to be lower than today : 
`value < new Date()`

```js
export function dateValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: no, the comparaison is ok with the '<' comparator. My question is about writing the ValidatorFn and the synthax of this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are asking for the `ValidationFn` syntax, it may look like this:

```
dateValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    // implementation of the validation
}
```

Usage:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    name : [,Validators.required],
    email: [,Validators.email],
    birthday: [,this.dateValidator],
    role: [,Validators.required]
  });
}
```

With [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) library:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

[...]

dateValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
  if (control.value) {
    const date = moment(control.value);
    const today = moment();
    if (date.isBefore(today)) {
      return { 'invalidDate': true }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: tks. you can see my comment on julianobrasil's response. It didn't work for me without parenthesis : birthday: [,this.dateValidator],

Comment: If you use my version of `dateValidator` without parenthesis, it will work. julianobrasil's `dateValidator` returns a ValidatorFn function at execution, my version of `dateValidator` is the ValidatorFn function itself - hence lack of parenthesis. :)

Comment: tks for the clarification!!

Comment: Yeah, I was honoring the signature he wanted to use in his question (`export function dateValidator(): ValidatorFn`). :)

Comment: @julianobrasil Understood

Answer (score 2):

You can see the [Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma615036946433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html).

```js
export function dateValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const today = new Date().getTime();

    if(!(control && control.value)) {
      // if there's no control or no value, that's ok
      return null;
    }

    // return null if there's no errors
    return control.value.getTime() > today 
      ? {invalidDate: 'You cannot use future dates' } 
      : null;
  }
}
```

And you can use like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      ...
      birthday: [new Date(), dateValidator()],
      ...
    });
  }
```

Comment: tks @julianobrasil! that is what I looked for. Unfortunately, the validator is not called as I enter the value using a datePicker. But it is maybe another issue.

Comment: I've put a demo link in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: tks a lot!! I used date: [new Date(), dateValidator] without parenthesis (strangely, the code before the return was hit (I try with a console). Now it's fine.